# Can't Install Pygame

Tags: python, macos, pygame, macos-sierra

So I had Pygame installed and running a while ago, and I kind of stopped programming for a bit. I recently came back to start again and found that none of my modules were installed anymore. When I try to reinstall Pygame, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 192, in main
    retcode = do_install(pkgs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 109, in do_install
    return pip.main(['install'] + pkgs) AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have tried running the command through command terminal and it didn't work. I'm on a Mac.

EDIT: Solved by reinstalling python - thanks for the help anyway guys :)

Comment: Does `pip` work for other modules or just Pygame?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to install Sklearn and I modified the packaging_tool.py:

#### add this

`from pip import __main__`

#### change the line 109:

`return pip.__main__._main(['install'] + pkgs)`

It works!